# getElementById issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this button:

```
<input type="button" value="Rep" 
    id="rep" name="rep" class="rep" style="width:50px" 
    onclick="triggerLabel(1);this.disabled=true;addRep(<?php echo  $comment_id; ?>);"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

     function triggerLabel($commentID)
     {
        var $theID="#"+$commentID;
        var $label=document.getElementById($theID).value;
        alert($label);
     }

</script>
```

The alert isn't triggered. I want to obtain the commentID and convert it to a string.. And I want that string to represent my element ID. The alert works, it retrieves #25. That's the id that I gave one of my labels..

```
echo '<label id="'.$comment_id.'">'.$avatarRep.'</label>';
```

It should retrieve that label, but unfortunately it fails..I get this:

> Error: document.getElementById($theID) is null
>   Source File: http://localhost/PoliticalForum/Thread/thread.php?threadID=15&page=1
>   Line: 246

What do I do?

That's how the label html control looks like when I view the source page:

```
<label id="25">6</label>
```

UPDATE:
I updated my answer. Take a look:

```
var $label=document.getElementById($commentID);
$label.value=9999;
```

The 9999 isnt inserted into the table..why?!?

UPDATE 2:
This doesnt work:

```
document.getElementById($commentID).value="88888";
```

The label isnt changed.

Comment: And just one thing - `<label>` doesn't have `value` property but `innerHTML`

Comment: See my answer, `label`s don't have a `value` property. Use `innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `getElementById` properly, i.e. remove the `#`:

```
var $label = document.getElementById($commentID);
```

or use jQuery:

```
var $label = $($theID);
```

Note that `label`s don't have a `value` property. If you want to get the inner text, use `innerHTML` or `.text()` with jQuery.

Also, before HTML5, IDs where not allowed to start with digits.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to supply the `#` for `getElementById`. Just the ID.
So write:

```
var $label=document.getElementById($commentID).value;
```

Another option is to get the element via the JQuery `$` function. Then you have to supply the `#`:

```
var $label=$($theID).val()
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("your_id_without_#_char")` will return you HTML element.

`$("#your_id_with_#_char")` will return you jQuery object.

You shouldn't use `#` for `document.getElementById()` function - just elem ID.

Answer (score 1):

Not add the "#" to your CommentID.
write:

```
 function triggerLabel($commentID)
 {
    var $theID=$commentID;
    var $label=document.getElementById($theID).value;
    alert($label);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` is not a jQuery, it's a DOM function so you don't need to place `#` at the front of id

Comment: getElementById is DOM, not native JS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the **#** in front of your id, you can use the `querySelector` method, but is not compatible with older browsers.

> Incompatible with: IE < 8, FFox < 3.5, Opera < 10, Safari < 3.2

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector

`document.querySelector('#id');`

You should not use the hash in your case

`document.getElementById('#id');`

in jquery you can use the hash

`$('#id');`

Comment: "Other browsers"? Other than what?